# Access column from composite type array in Postgres C API

Tags: sql, c, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I access array of composite values like this:

```
PG_GETARG_ARRAYTYPE_P(0)
/* Then I deconstruct it into C array */
deconstruct_array()
/* Later I iterate thru values and attempt to access columns of my composite type */
GetAttributeByName(input_data1[i], "keyColumnName", &isnull[0])
```

This is how it looks in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM my_c_function(array[(44, 1)::comp_type, (43, 0)::comp_type], array[(42, 1)::comp_type, (43, 1)::comp_type]);
```

Expected result:

```
array[(44, 1)::comp_type, (42, 1)::comp_type, (43, 1)::comp_type] /*order doesn't matter*/
```

But this does not work, because `GetAttributeByName()` works only with `HeapTupleHeader`, sadly I have array of `Datum`.
Normally you get `HeapTupleHeader` by accessing function attribute like so: `PG_GETARG_HEAPTUPLEHEADER(0)` but that is not meant for arrays (or I'm wrong?).

So is there some function/makro to get columns from `Datum` that is composite type or to convert composite type `Datum` into `HeapTuple`? I have gone as deep as `heap_getattr()`, but can't really find anything useful. Can't remember if there is already some kind of function that would access composite array in similar fashion and would show me how to do it.

For the context:
I have 2 arrays of composite type and I want to write C function for fast concatenation of them. I however cannot simply add right argument to left, because they could share "key" column and in that case I would like result to have only values from right side.

This is simple task in plpgSQL (unnest, full join, array_agg) but is very slow. I have tested the same task in hstore and json and both are much faster than unnest+array_agg, but I cannot use those data types without extensive database structure changes, so I was looking for different solution.

Comment: Sidenote: you could try a [`language sql` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) too. They are a lot faster than the `plpgsql` ones.

Comment: @pozs yes, I forgot to mention - I did try it and it was no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess all you need is the `DatumGetHeapTupleHeader` macro defined in `fmgr.h`.